# Does 'bringing people' make sense?

Tags: grammar

The passage is as follows:

> There are lots more advantages to a mobile phone other than the merits mentioned above. With the countless developments that it has brought and is still bringing people, one can say that it is everything in one portable handheld device.

So basically this passage talks about the advantages of a mobile phone. What I don't get is the phrase "With the countless developments that it has brought and is still bringing people". Aren't we supposed to use "bringing to people" instead of "bringing people"? I would be glad if you could help me understand why the phrase "bringing people" is correct.

Comment: In your sentence, "people" is in the dative case (= to or for people). This is a vestige of Old English that had grammatical cases. *See Dative Shift in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_shift*  "People* can be seen as the indirect object, or as an adverbial

Comment: ... On the other hand, 'lots more X's other than' is at best unusual.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Nobody ever said there should have been an extra preposition in the movie title [*Bring **TO** Me the Head of Alfredo Garcia*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_Me_the_Head_of_Alfredo_Garcia) Though whether technology can "bring people developments" seems more a matter of questionable semantics than syntax.

Comment: Thank you all for answering my question!

Comment: English does **not** have a dative case. It's just nonsense to say it has.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I was also thinking of the first sentence that has in it "...more....other than...." It is common to say more....than or other...than, but...? If I was to write, it would be "There are lots more advantages to a mobile phone than the merits mentioned above." OR "There are lots of advantages to a mobile phone other than the merits mentioned above."  Meanings, of course, may vary a little. I'm sorry, it is not what the OP has sought to clarify, though.

Comment: @Ram Pillai 'Besides the advantages already mentioned, there are many others.'

Answer (score 1):

I would analyse it more simply as "With the countless developments that it [[has brought] and [is still bringing]] people ___", where the anaphoric gap is the direct object, and "people" is the indirect object, of both verbs.

CGEL:1292 has this example: "the book [which you recommended and she enjoyed so much]" in which they understand the relative pronoun "which" as object of both "recommended" and "enjoyed".

As for the presence of "to", I personally find the sentence marginally clearer with it than without it, though both are grammatically sound.  With "to", "people" functions as an oblique complement of the verbs; without "to" it is an indirect complement.

[This was intended as a comment on BillJ's answer.]

Answer (score 0):

> *With the countless developments that it* [*has brought* ___ ___] [*and is*
> *still bringing people* ___]

The bracketed elements form a coordination of two VPs.

In the first coordinate, the two gaps represent the Oi "people" and the Od "developments". In the second coordinate 'gap' represents the Od "developments".

There is nothing to be gained by replacing the Oi, i.e. the recipient "people", with the PP "to people".